# How to update asset_packager for heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to modify javascript files in a Ruby on Rails application in HEROKU. Every time I modified something, it did not have any effect on the application. Thanks to a member in this web site, I realized that my application is using asset packager. This asset packager creates a file called base_packaged.js that has all the javascript file compressed.

Because I am new with Heroku and using Windows I modify everything with a text editor, in this case I use notepad++. So when I change the file for example quote.js, nothing happens. I suppose The file quote.js is changed but the compressed base_packaged.js is not been updated. So when I push the file using GIT GUI to Heroku, only the file quote.js is updated but heroku does not recognized that change and does not modify the base_package.js.

How can I modify edit or update the base_package.js. Obviously file is very important I don't want to make a mess with my application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is surely a suboptimal solution but I have had the same exact problem and this is what I have done. Go into any file such as your rake file in your public directory and just add something to a comment or add another comment.

Git will see this change and your other changes will get added along. I completely understand that this is a hack but It is super easy you works!

Comment: Hello codeglot. I modified the file rakefile. I did not find any file called rake in Public. But nothing is changing. it is the same.

Comment: Ok, I will checkout asset packager and see what the problem might be.

Comment: Hey, might get some time to check this out today :)